# No enclosing instance of type ContactsXmpp is accessible?

Tags: android, syntax-error, static-methods

this is the class i am using

```
public class ContactsXmpp extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private static Context ctx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_xmpp_sip);

    ctx = this;
}
```

i am getting error when i call asynctask from this method. this is the error 
`No enclosing instance of type ContactsXmpp is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ContactsXmpp (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ContactsXmpp).`

```
private static void alert( String str, final String name ) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);       
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(str + ": " + name);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {                 
            Subscription(name);          
            new ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin().execute();     ///** error getting here..                                
        }
    }); 

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            unSubscribe(name);
        }           
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();       
    alertDialog.show();         
}
```

Asynctask here

```
public class ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin extends AsyncTask<AfterLogging, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog _dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {          
        super.onPreExecute();            
        Log.e(TAG, " GmailXMPP_AfterLogin onPreExecute" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void feed) {
        //ProgressBar_hide();       
        _dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(TAG, " GmailXMPP_AfterLogin onPostExecute" );        
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(AfterLogging... arg0) {

        Log.e(TAG, " GmailXMPP_AfterLogin doInBackground" );

        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: make sure you are assign  Activity context to `ctx` in `onCreate` method of `ContactsXmpp` before calling  alert` method

Comment: yes, i did it correct i was assigned in onCreate() method only. updated my code look at that.

Comment: new ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin().execute(ContactsXmpp.this);  try this i think help this one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate the `ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin` class in the `static` method of `alert`(I'm assuming that both are in the `ContactsXmpp` activity). The problem is that `ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin` is declared as being an *inner class* and inner classes need an instance of the enclosing class to be created(they require this connection). In the static `alert` method you don't have this instance so the compiler throws that error. You have several options to solve the problem, the one I would recommend is to either make `ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin` as a nested class in `ContactsXmpp`(declared like `public static class ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin...`) or completely move it in its own java file(if you need a connection to the `Activity`'s `Context` simply pass a reference to that `ctx` in the `AsyncTask`'s constructor).

You could also use the `ctx` variable to create the instance of `ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin` like:

```
ctx.new ColorsXMPP_AfterLogin();
```