# Context type in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-context, fragmentpageradapter

I have implemented a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with 4 tabs and I have associated a fragment to each of them. One of the views loads a `GridView` with images as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.init, container, false);

final GridView grid = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);            
grid.setNumColumns(2);
grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

return view;
}
```

The problem is that the method `new ImageAdapter(context)` receives as a parameter a variable type Context to load in method `newImageView (context)` that it needs this type of variable and passing `getActivity()` I have next mistake:

> No enclosing instance of type IniSel is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type IniSel (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of IniSel).

(IniSel is the Class name)

How I can fix?

How do I pass a variable Context type within a class that inherits from Fragment?

Comment: change `class ImageAdapter` to `static class ImageAdapter`

Comment: Maybe you use inner class, you can refer this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107999/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-contactsxmpp-is-accessible